# Qt qaxwidget setcontrol() from file name in order to "xxx.doc" show in widget,but then the winword.exe process can't quit

Tags: qt, ms-word, com, qt4

I've tried two ways to load a Word document into Qt qaxwidget, but neither successfully quits the winword.exe process.

My first attempt

```
ui->axWidget->setControl("D:/1.doc");
QAxObject *app = ui->axWidget->querySubObject("Application");
app->dynamicCall("Quit()");
```

Sometimes the following will work, but not reliably:

```
ui->axWidget->("Word.Application");
setProperty("DisplayAlerts", false);
setProperty("Visible", false);
ui->axWidget->setControl("D:/1.doc");//then call this line of code

QAxObject *app = ui->axWidget->querySubObject("Application");
ui->axWidget->dynamicCall("Close(bool)", false);
ui->axWidget->clear();
app->dynamicCall("Quit()");
```

What should I do to properly clos thee "winword.exe" process?

My enviroment is qt4.8.0+vs2008.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution should be correct,but there are some other thing that limit me from closing the process.
The second solution is completely an error，When I call `ui->axWidget->setControl("D:/1.doc");`,"Word.Application" is out of control.
So,we wanna load a **Word document** into **Qt qaxwidget** firmly,my solution is

```
QProcess p;  
QString c = "taskkill /im winword.exe /f";  
p.execute(c);  
p.close();
```